# JSTL forEach reverse order

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Using JSTL's `forEach` tag, is it possible to iterate in reverse order?

Comment: The accepted answer of Eddie on this question might not work for everyone. At least, it did not work for me using Jakarta's (Apache's) implementation of JSTL 1.1 and Sun's (Oracle's) implementation of JSTL 1.2. Also the spec mandates that `step` must be `>=1`. For an alternative, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879248/jstl-cforeach-decremental-number-loop-impossible

Comment: The good explanation for **decrement** is [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3883595/621951](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3883595/621951)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you are using `forEach` to create an integer loop, you can go forward or backward, but it requires some work.  It turns out you cannot do this, for example:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="10" end="0" step="-1">
    ....
</c:forEach>
```

because the spec requires the step is positive.  But you can always loop in forward order and then use `<c:var` to convert the incrementing number into a decrementing number:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10" step="1">
   <c:var var="decr" value="${10-i}"/>
    ....
</c:forEach>
```

However, when you are doing a `forEach` over a Collection of any sort, I am not aware of any way to have the objects in reverse order.  At least, not without first sorting the elements into reverse order and **then** using `forEach`.

I have successfully navigated a `forEach` loop in a desired order by doing something like the following in a JSP:

```
<%
List list = (List)session.getAttribute("list");
Comparator comp = ....
Collections.sort(list, comp);
%>


<c:forEach var="bean" items="<%=list%>">
     ...
</c:forEach>
```

With a suitable Comparator, you can loop over the items in any desired order.  This works.  But I am not aware of a way to say, very simply, iterate in reverse order the collection provided.

Comment: I updated my answer to add a code sample for how I've iterated over a Collection in a desired order.

Comment: or better yet, create the collection in the order it will be used in. jsps are not good places for data massaging.

Comment: Yow, -1 for showing someone how to do something?  We're only allowed to show the ideal way?  Geez.

Comment: @Eddie - I didn't downvote your answer, but when I tried your solution I got the same problem as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879248/jstl-cforeach-decremental-number-loop-impossible. So that may be the reason for it, as your solution doesn't seem to always work (didn't work for me).

Comment: The original question was about a Collection (see the comment above), and that worked.  I corrected the part that was in error.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

Building on the answer given by [Eddie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/712062/578821), I used the following code to iterate over a collection in reverse order.

Given a collection called "list", which stores a list of people.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<%-- Keep a reference to the size of the collection --%>
<c:set var="num_people" value="${fn:length(list)}" />

<%-- Iterate through items. Start at 1 to avoid array index out of bounds --%>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${num_people}" step="1">
    <c:set var="person" value="${list[num_people-i]}" />

    ${person.name}<br />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also consider rolling a custom JSTL function that returned a reversed copy of your list, backed by something like this:

```
public static <T extends Object> List<T> reverse(List<T> list) {
    List<T> copy = Collections.emptyList();
    Collections.copy(copy, list);
    Collections.reverse(copy);
    return copy;
}
```

Doesn't work for Collections, but as mentioned in another answer, the concept of ordering is a bit vague for some collections.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with a little bit trick:-

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="10" var="i" step="1">
     <c:set var="j" value="${10-i+1}" scope="page"></c:set>
     <c:out value="${j}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

OutPut will be :- 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: All you did was copy what is in the link given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could [reverse the Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) before adding it to your model.

This also means you would not need to do anything in the view layer to achieve your requirement.