# JSTL c:forEach, decremental number loop impossible?

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to print decremental numbers like:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="10" end="0" step="-1">
    ... ${i} ...
</c:forEach>
```

then I got jsp exception:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: 'step' <= 0
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.validateStep(LoopTagSupport.java:459)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag.setStep(ForEachTag.java:60)
    ....
```

but this answer says it is possible to loop in both ways:

[JSTL forEach reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712046/jstl-foreach-reverse-order)

What's wrong with me?

Comment: That other question was really about how to loop over a Collection backwards.  I corrected my answer so the other part is also correct.  Nothing is wrong with you.  My answer had a mistake.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am not sure how the answerer of the other question got it to work, but I can't get it to work here with the reference JSTL implementation.

Anyway, you can achieve the requirement with following:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10" step="1">
    ... ${10 - i} ...
</c:forEach>
```

Or if you'd like to avoid duplication of `10`:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10" step="1" varStatus="loop">
    ... ${loop.end - i + loop.begin} ...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Right, the spec states: If specified, step must be >= 1

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, without using the `var` attribute:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="10" varStatus="loop">
  ${loop.end - loop.count + 1}
</c:forEach>
```

Note that `step` is omitted too, because its default value is `1`.