# I am trying to iterate for each loop in reverse order but not able to succeed

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, jsp-tags

I am trying to iterate a collection through for each loop on jsp. My requirement is that I want to iterate a for loop in reverse order. Please refer following code for reference :

Working Code :Iterating from start to end works fine :

```
<c:forEach items="${field.values}" var="value" varStatus="statusInner">
    ${value.value}
   </c:forEach>
```

Tried to iterate in reverse order :

```
<c:forEach items="${field.values}" var="value" begin="${fn:length(field.values)}"end="0"  varStatus="statusInner">
    ${value.value}
   </c:forEach>
```

Can anyone please help me out in solving my problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (access reverse instead of iterating reverse):

```
<c:set var="fieldLength" value="${fn:length(field.values)}"/>
<c:forEach items="${field.values}" varStatus="status">
  ${field.values[fieldLength - status.count]}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: When i tried this code i encountered the following error :

Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '1' not found on type java.util.LinkedHashSet

Comment: yes, because a LinkedHashSet is not accessible directly by an index. A solution (not a nice one) would to use .ToArray() for the hashmap an then iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a step of -1 so it decrements the index.  Without specifying a decrementing step the index will increase for each iteration.

```
<c:forEach items="${field.values}" var="value" 
     begin="${fn:length(field.values)" end="0"  
          varStatus="statusInner" step="-1">
    ${value}
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Are you sure that code works? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879248/jstl-cforeach-decremental-number-loop-impossible/3883595

Comment: Tried the same but could not worked out:(

Comment: When i tried this code i encountered the following error : Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '1' not found on type java.util.LinkedHashSet

Comment: @jACOB Remove the `.value` portion of the expression.  The value is already in the variable.

Comment: @KevinBowersox You forgat a } after ${fn:length(field.values)

Comment: Negative steps aren't permitted.

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: 'step' <= 0
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.validateStep(LoopTagSupport.java:496)