# JSTL foreach - how to loop from last to first

Tags: java, jsp, loops, foreach, jstl

```
<c:set var="eventsLastIndex" value="${events.size() - 1}" />
<c:forEach items="${events}" var="event"
        begin="${eventsLastIndex}" end="0" step="-1">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

This code throws exception: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: 'step' <= 0

But, how to iterate from last element?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879248/jstl-cforeach-decremental-number-loop-impossible);

You can use sthg like this;

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10" step="1" varStatus="loop">
    ... ${loop.end - i + loop.begin} ...
</c:forEach>
```

You must write foreach as usual, and while getting value you must get decremental.

Answer (score 0):

**step** - loop increment variable, defaults to 1.

**Step is an int value and accepts only positive values, not a mandatory field to be given, by default values is 1.**

```
<c:forEach items="${myCollection}" var="myColl"  step="2">
    Every alternate object: ${myColl.name}
</c:forEach>
```

Above example displays every alternate school in the collection (i.e., 1,3,5,7 and so on).