# jstl c:foreach can the step be 0.5

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have following code in my jsp

```
    <c:forEach var="starCounter" begin="1" end="5" step="1">
        <c:if test="${starCounter le averageRating}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${starCounter gt averageRating}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

I want to change the step for 1 to 0.5 but unable to do so cause when I change the step to 0.5, I get the following error and my jsp doesn't compile

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.5"
```

As mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879248/jstl-cforeach-decremental-number-loop-impossible), it seems like step must be >= 1.

Is there any way to do what I want to achieve?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add my final answer. So here it is. I just added another variable `starHalfStepCounter` and played around it.

The updated code is

```
<c:forEach var="starCounter" begin="1" end="5">
        <c:set var="starHalfStepCounter" value="${starCounter - 0.5}" />                                        
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${starCounter le averageRating}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
            </c:when>                                       
            <c:when test="${starCounter gt averageRating}">                                             
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${starHalfStepCounter le averageRating}">                                                     
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half"></i>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
                    </c:otherwise>                                              
                </c:choose>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) for `foreach`, `step` is `int` and it cannot take a double/float value like `0.5` as you need. So IMO not possible,

Comment: I was also under the same assumption. Will try out to do this in some other way. Thanks for your help

Comment: @BalwinderSingh Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JSP scriplets :)

```
    <%
        for (double i = 0; i <= 5; i+=0.5) {
            if (i < averageRating) {
    %>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
    <%
            } else {
    %>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
    <%
            }
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, came up with a simple solution, code shows option creation for a select element from 12 to 36 with step of .25:

```
<select>
<c:set value=".25" var="doubleStep" />
<c:forEach begin="${12/doubleStep}" end="${36/doubleStep}" var="step">
    <option value="${step * doubleStep}">${step * doubleStep}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Works very well!